# Can you have a lower or upper triangular matrix plot when plotting correlations using pheatmap in R?

Tags: r, pheatmap

Say we use the mtcars data from corrplot. How can we obtain a triangular matrix plot using pheatmap?

```
library(corrplot)
library(pheatmap)

M <- cor(mtcars)
pheatmap(M)
```

Comment: Why do you persist in `pheatmap()`? `corrplot(M, method = "color", type = "lower", addgrid.col = "grey")` is not what you want ?

Comment: @DarrenTsai I need the dendrogram from pheatmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple way to get a triangular matrix plot from `pheatmap`.

```
M[lower.tri(M)] <- NA
pheatmap(M, cluster_rows=F, cluster_cols=F, na_col="white")
```

[image]

Comment: how to hide the lower part fully ? no display

Comment: @PesKchan Try adding `border_color ="white"` in `pheatmap`.