# how to generate a heatmap of a correlation matrix with clustering and phylogenetic tree

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, phylogeny, cross-correlation

i'm stuck with R, i don't know what package use to create the plot i would like. I have a pairwise matrix with the similiarity between genomes.
Something like:

```
GENOMES   genomeA   genomeB   genomeC
genomeA   100       75.5      13.2
genome B  42.3      100       47.3
genomeC   90        46        100
```

and at the end i would like to have the plots:

one with heatmap of correlation (triangular or full) with clustering

one with heatmap of correlation (triangular or full) with possibility to add my own phylogenetic tree to see the difference between the phylogeny and the clustering

i tried a lot of differents heatmap with differents packages but they are all classical heatmap and not correlation one.
with heatmap i get something like this :

```
mtscaled = as.matrix(scale(test1))
heatmap(mtscaled, scale='none')
```

[image: fun but not very accurate]

fun but not very accurate..

i would like more something like this + the possibility to add dendogram and tree, if someone can think about cool package!
[image]

[image]

like this it's "just" a clustering but if i want to add my own phylogenetic tree, how to reorder everyone according to the tree?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you have a lower or upper triangular matrix plot when plotting correlations using pheatmap in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670791/can-you-have-a-lower-or-upper-triangular-matrix-plot-when-plotting-correlations)

Comment: @starja unfortunatly no, i will edit my post, it's not the upper or lower triangular matrix that i really want, it's more adding dendogram by clustering AND add a phylogenetic tree and then reorder all the genome according to this tree